# Duplicate does not satisfy me

Tags: discussion

Suppose I ask a question on site and it is marked as duplicate. What if the accepted answer of duplicate question does not satisfy me?

So even though I am not satisfied with accepted answer of the duplicate question, my question will be marked as duplicate. Any solution?

Comment: For that, you can edit you question and ask more specific like what exactly you want which is not mentioned in the other question and flag to reopen. It might be reopened

Comment: Can you clarify which is the question of your you're talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Stack Exchange questions are not only for their askers

When you ask a question, you might have a strong personal interest in getting an answer, but, if it is a good and widely applicable question (likely if it's already been asked) your question and its answers will also be a great help to others interested in the same subject when they visit the site in the future. It's not only you who could benefit but potentially thousands of others! So, your personal satisfaction in an answer might be overlooked by reviewers, who have the interests of all future visitors in mind. If they see good quality answers, they will feel that the site is working well, even if the person who asks the question hasn't got the answer they really wanted.

#### But we really want you to get a good answer...

It seems reasonable that in return for this great contribution to the site by you, the community ought to try to help you get an answer that you find satisfying, one that really answers the question you really intended to ask. That might have been misunderstood or not understood, and you might have to do a bit of extra work to convey what you really wanted to know.

#### What you can do if this happens

Sometimes it happens that a question is closed as a duplicate when the question is not really the same, or reviewers might not have read all the available answers before voting to close. Mistakes happen. If your question is closed wrongly, you can edit it to point out how it is different to the other question or that the answers to the other question don't answer your question. Editing the question body within the first few days of closing will automatically send the question to a reopen queue where reviewers can look at the changes and decide whether to reopen the question.

It might happen that your question is the same, or that you think it's not but reviewers vote to leave your question closed. If you're not satisfied with any of the answers to the other question<sup>1</sup>, you can [offer a bounty](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on the old question to ask for a new answer. You can say in the bounty message what kind of answer you are looking for. If you don't have enough reputation to spare for a bounty, you might well be able to interest someone else in offering one for you by visiting [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) and explaining your need. Even if nobody wants to help you out with a bounty, they might help you out with the answer you're looking for, or advice on how to get your question reopened, or frame a new question likely to get the kind of answer you want.

---

1 <sub>In your question you talked about being unsatisfied with the accepted answer. An answer being accepted just means that the OP of the question was satisfied with it. That doesn't mean it was the best answer and in fact other answers are often more popular than the accepted one. I advise you not to pay too much attention to the acceptance of answers, but more to the votes. After all, the person who asks the question probably isn't the most expert on the topic if they needed to ask a question about it, so their judgement on the answers might not be very authoritative.</sub>